# How to improve the accuracy of SVM regression results (has saturation at high values)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, matlab, regression-coefficients

I have a question about using SVM regression in matlab. My training data set has a distribution like gaussian (below figure. A lot of data in 0-5, only few data >5). I separate this dataset into 2/3 for training and 1/3 for validation. They follow the same distribution

[image: distribution of training dataset].

The function I used is like this:
fitrsvm(Xtrain,Ytrain,'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','gaussian','OptimizeHyperparameters','all',    'HyperparameterOptimizationOptions',struct('AcquisitionFunctionName','expected-improvement-plus'));

The validation show bad results for large values (saturation)
[image: regression results].

Is it because there are few data >5 in the training dataset? I find 'weights' parameter in matlab fitrsvm function. Do I need to add somes weights to the training dataset? If it doesn't work, how can I improve the accuracy?

Comment: What's meant by _"small distribution"_?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. What do you mean with "values with more distribution" and " values with small distribution"? Do you mean very extreme values, which are of course very rare in the training sample, since you're saying that it has been drawn by a Gaussian distribution? Or do you mean that the distribution of your training data is a binary mixture distribution, with an high probability of occurence for one of the two distributions making up the mixture, and a low probability of occurence for the other? Can you describe in more detail the actual problem and show a sample of your data?

Comment: Your data in the histogram are absolutely nothing like Gaussian. What are they actually? Are they counts, eg? What are the variables you are working with? Why are you using an SVM, which is usually used for classification, when you seem to have non-categorical data?

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong expression. It is a kind of ecological variable ranging from 0 to 8. In the distribution figure, the y-axis is number of values. I know SVM also can be used for regression.